# Infinite Sets Proof

Tags: infinite-product, multisets

I have a few questions regarding this problem below:

> Prove that if A and B are finite sets, then A ≈ B if and only if |A| = |B|.

Would I assume that |A| = |B|? Which would obviously make A ≈ B and B ≈ A for all sets A and B.
Then would I say that A = {1, 2 ,3} and since |A| = |B| doesn't that mean they have the same cardinality which would make A = B instead of A ≈ B. I'm confused in this aspect. Any help is appeciated!

Comment: What does this symbol means ≈ ?

Comment: It is used to say items are approximately or about equal

Comment: @Earthbound27 OK, what does *that* mean? Can you give us the precise definition of "$\approx$"?

Comment: I apologise it does indeed mean a bijection in this case.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that definition, as well as the definition of $|A|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\approx$ means "there is a bijection between" a (sketch of a) proof will be as follows:

$(\Leftarrow)$ Assume $|A|=|B|$. Then, since they are finite sets, by definition there is an $n\in\omega$, and there are bijections $f:A\to n$ and $g:B\to n$ (precisely, $n$ is the cardinality of $A$ and $B$). Therefore $g^{-1}\circ f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Assume $A\approx B$. Then there is a bijection $f:A\to B$. Since $A$ and $B$ are finite there are $n,m\in\omega$ and bijections $g:A\to n$ and $h:B\to m$. Now one can easily show that there is a bijection between $n$ and $m$. Hence $n=m$